# How long does Google Books keep the limit on the pages viewed?

Tags: google-books

When reading a book on Google Books I reached the limit for number of previewable pages viewed.

How long should I wait before the restriction is lifted so that I can view other previewable pages that I haven't read?

Comment: The block used to be IP-based and last "forever", according to Brewster Kahle. https://archive.org/details/AaronSwartzMemorialAtTheInternetArchive?start=4680 Now things are less straightforward but even nastier.